# Vuex: getters should be function but "getters.default" in module "customer" is {}

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I structured my Vuex store in several modules and now I'm facing a strange Vuex error that I am unable to solve:

```
Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.default" in module "customer" is {}.
at assert (vuex.esm.js?358c:97)
at eval (vuex.esm.js?358c:271)
at eval (vuex.esm.js?358c:85)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachValue (vuex.esm.js?358c:85)
at eval (vuex.esm.js?358c:270)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at assertRawModule (vuex.esm.js?358c:265)
at ModuleCollection.register (vuex.esm.js?358c:191)
at eval (vuex.esm.js?358c:205)
```

The Structure of my Vuex store is build on the following pattern

```
- store
-- index.js
-- modules
--- customer
---- index.js
---- actions.js
---- getters.js
---- mutations.js
```

Here is my sores basic index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import customerModule from './modules/customer/index'
import globalModule from './modules/global/index'
import projectModule from './modules/project/index'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    customer: customerModule,
    global: globalModule,
    project: projectModule
  }
})
```

my modules/customer/index.js:

```
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

const state = {
  customers: []
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: state,
  actions: actions,
  mutations: mutations,
  getters: getters
}
```

my modules/customer/getters.js:

```
const customers = state => state.customers

export default {
  customers
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on here uand why I get this strange error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me, despite what you did being the example Vuex uses in the documentation.

Use

`import getters from './getters'`

instead of

`import * as getters from './getters'`